# How to launch multiple urls per process with cURL?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, xargs

I am trying to download a list of URLs with cURL with multiple URLs per process. The following works but it returns a weird result if the `xargs -L` parameter is more than 1. I want to launch 8 processes with each getting 4 urls so I don't spawn too many.

```
curl url1...url4

cat urls.txt | xargs -n 1 -L 4 -P 8 curl -I -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code} %{url_effective}\n"
```

The result is quite chaotic.

```
503 http://somewebsite.txt
404 http://somewebsite.txt
503 http://somewebsite.txt
404 http://somewebsite.txt
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 24 Nov 2016 10:11:36 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

404 http://somewebsite.txt
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 24 Nov 2016 10:11:36 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

404 http://somewebsite.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not look like a client side issue. It looks like a server issue, like a jsp which does not compile.

You can investigate with `curl -vvv` to have more information.

Plus, when issue solved, you likely want to use `xargs -n 4` instead of "-n 1 -L 4".

Comment: Does -n4 concatenate lines? To "url 1 url 2 url 3 url 4"

Comment: This happens with any server btw.

Comment: Yes, "-n 4" concatenate lines. This is what you want if you want to decrease spawn.

Comment: This works for me against "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" server. Articles are downloaded and connections are reused.